# Is it possible to build a custom tree structured warehouse system with LDAP?

Tags: spring-data, openldap

My company is building a factory warehouse managing system with springboot and spring-data-ldap. The old system only supports warehouse with 3 tiers like this:

warehouse (contains) storagearea(s) (contains) storagelocation(s)

This kind of structure is way too strict for customers since their warehouses are uniquely different. We are thinking of building a system that users are able to config their own warehouse tiers without we hard coding the relations in java.

Now I am migrating mysql table schema of warehouse, storagearea and storagelocation, into LDAP.  But it seems we have to define new objectClasses in ApacheDS since the attributes are not defined in OpenLdap.

Creating a new attribute type requires an OID, which is a unique number that has to be acquired by applying online from some website.

Is it possible to build a system like this? 
Is there any way of obtaining OID or randomly create one?

Answer (score 1):

That is possible. You need to aquire an OID from the IANA (Here is the link to the form: http://pen.iana.org/pen/PenApplication.page) and then you can create your own LDAP Schema entities.

And as long as the customer can create their tree with your schema entries there is nothing stopping you. And when you need to refactor your schema: do it.

You can find more on OIDs at https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/OID or o  wikipedia.

Comment: Is it possible to get OIDs if I do not apply online.